# XmlValueDisconnectedException when remove Formula

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi

I trying to reade an Excel file with java poi. I iterate through the rows and then through the cells. To reade the cell i use this method:

```java
  private String readCell(Cell cell) {
        try {
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case NUMERIC:
                    if (format.isParseNumbersToInt()) {
                        return ((int) cell.getNumericCellValue()) + "";
                    } else {
                        return cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
                    }
                case STRING:
                case _NONE:
                    return cell.getStringCellValue();
                case FORMULA:
                    if (format.isUseCashedFormulaValue()) {
                        cell.removeFormula();
                        return readCell(cell);
                    } else {
                        return cell.getCellFormula() + "";
                    }
                case BLANK:
                    return format.getBlankValue();
                case BOOLEAN:
                    return cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
                case ERROR:
                    if (format.isReadErrorCells()) {
                        return "ERROR_" + cell.getErrorCellValue();
                    } else {
                        return format.getErrorCellValue();
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to read cell: " + cell.getAddress(), e);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown CellType: " + cell.getCellType().name());
    }
```

At one point the XmlValueDisconnectedException throws:

```
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.getStringValue(XmlObjectBase.java:1529)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.convertSharedFormula(XSSFCell.java:491)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getCellFormula(XSSFCell.java:469)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDeleteFormula(XSSFSheet.java:4654)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.removeFormulaImpl(XSSFCell.java:571)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellBase.removeFormula(CellBase.java:182)
    at de.heuboe.base.excel.controller.reader.ExcelReader.readCell(ExcelReader.java:356)
    ... 89 more
```

This Point looks the same as all others. The Point of the file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WRsJ.png)

in D219 is the string in the following cells is a referenze to the cell one row over, e.g. D220: "=D219" and D221: "=D220". The same for the columns E, F and G.

The hole file looks like this and works but at this point the programm crashes. And i don't know why.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the StackTrace, there is a problem with a shared formula.

If you have formulas `=D6`, `=D7`, `=D8`,  ... `=D219`, `=D220`, ... and so on in column `D`, then not for all cells the complete formula is stored. Instead only one cell stores the complete formula and following cells only store shared reference to the formula.

In `OOXML` this looks like so :

In `XML` of cell `D8`: `<f ref="D8:D300" t="shared" si="1">D7</f>`

In `XML` of cell `D9:D300`: `<f t="shared" si="1"/>`

This `Excel` behavior tends to be fragile if somewhat else than `Excel` manipulates rows containing such shared formulas.

`Cell.removeFormula` is a pretty new feature in `apache poi`. It might be buggy. But as it is designed it should know about such shared formulas and respect those. So to get what really leads to that `XmlValueDisconnectedException` one would need the `Excel` file. There one could have a look into the sheet's `XML` and check whether someting in the shared formula's `XML` is different from the default which is expected by `XSSFCell.convertSharedFormula`.

But do you really need `Cell.removeFormula`? Because if the goal is simply to get the cashed formula value instead of the formula string itself but to avoid evaluating, then one could get that cashed formula value the same way as the other cell values but dependent on the cached formula result type.

Example:

```
...
case FORMULA:
 if (isUseCashedFormulaValue) {
  //cell.removeFormula();
  //return readCell(cell);
  switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
   case NUMERIC:
    return String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
   case STRING:
    return cell.getStringCellValue();
   case BOOLEAN:
    return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
   case ERROR:
    return "ERROR_" + cell.getErrorCellValue();
  }
 } else {
  return cell.getCellFormula();
 }
...
```